# How to add attributes for a Simple Product on Checkout Page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Been trying to figure out how to add attributes... for example the size of a product on the checkout page of woocommerce for wordpress.  Seems simple enough, but all searches I do on this point me to how to add custom fields to woocommerce using hooks.  But I don't want a custom field.  I just want to add in the size attribute for Simple Products on the checkout page only so people are reminded of the size... can someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0):

You can add attributes from admin side. There is no need to use any hooks for this. In admin side go to `products->products` and edit the product for which you want to add attribute. There below the product description you will find attributes tab there you can add your `custom product attribute`.

And you can also create common attribute for all the products from `Products->Attributes`. Here Add New Attribute and after saving it click on configure terms button to add attribute value

Comment: Yes... I already did this, but when you add that product to your cart and go to the checkout page, the attributes do not show under the title of the product on this page... how to get the size attribute to show under the title on the checkout page... like variations do??

Comment: Can you please provide the link? 

on checkout page(`checkout->review-order.php`) check `print_r($cart_item)` below the `<?php echo WC()->cart->get_item_data( $cart_item ); ?>` then fetch the attribute from the array.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me out totally, and got it working by calling `$product_attributes = get_post_meta($cart_item['product_id'], '_product_attributes', true);` and than using `$product_attributes['size']['value']` to get the value of it.  Cheers :)

Comment: If your question is solved please mark it as solved.

Comment: sorry @SolomonClosson its not OK but its tick mark.

Comment: That would mean that you're answer was the solution.  But it wasn't.  Your comment was helpful, but not the solution, and your answer wasn't the solution for sure.  No offense.

Comment: its ok none taken. glad if it helped